# Which mechanism may be used to access Java methods which conflict with JavaScript keywords?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, interop

I've a Javascript source that uses a Java class that defines a "delete" method (using jdk6 scripting). Since delete is a keyword, I cannot invoke that method.

In JavaFX script any sequence of characters enclosed in <> is treated as a lexical identifier. So you can use "insert", that is a keyword, as an identifier:

```
var textField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
textField.<<insert>>("Hello World");
```

Javascript provides a way to protect keywords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript you would do:

```
textField["insert"]("Hello World");
```